# I am trying to extend a base class which has Id in two different subclass to hit JPA query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have class BaseClass

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "childpart")   @NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class BaseClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    String child_part_no;

}
```

I have two subclasses SubClassA and SubClassB

both class extending baseClass which has ID

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "childpart") 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Data
public class SubclassA extends Pg6p0012_01ChildpartBaseQueryModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String component_qty;
}
```

and I am using JPA native query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT child_part_no, component_qty FROM childpart where part_no = :p_part_no", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<ResultModel>getChildpart2Result(@Param("p_part_no") String p_part_no);
```

the structure of the project is like : single repository for all the queries which are using same table and there are different models for every query which is extending baseModel as shown above .

**but the error is :** Object [id=1J2143980000] was not of the specified subclass,loaded object was of wrong class

please provide solution.

Comment: Base class is supposed to have a ID only which will be inherited in all the sub classes, how can I use JPA annotation there

Comment: Annotate you super class with `javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass`

Comment: Thanx a lot ... its done

Comment: Please mark this question as duplicate to the question in the comment.